# Mechanism design with known utilities (game theory)

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm trying to prove that in an n-party setting, where each party has a private value, the dominant strategy is always to reveal it. I'm assuming that parties only care about monetary payoffs and therefore I can directly model a utility function that is known and leveraged by the mechanism I'm designing.

Is there any problem with designing a mechanism when the utilities are known? I know that in general the preferences are not strictly monetary and are not well-defined, so I couldn't find any papers that design a direct mechanism, in which truth is a dominant strategy, but where the utilities are known.

It sounds to me like my problem is actually easier because of this assumption, but still correct.

Comment: What sort of model for a game are you using? Like, everyone receives secret information, then chooses whether to deliver a message (of some form) which are simultaneously revealed, then everyone chooses a strategy and the result is chosen as a function of the strategies and secret informations? I find it very doubtful that this is true in any broad sense (even if people are constrained to reveal the truth or to say nothing), but...

Comment: I'm considering a direct mechanism - everyone has a secret and simultaneously send a message to the center which could either be the secret or a lie. I'm treating 'not sending a message' as sending a wrong message. The center then computes a specific function - so I wouldn't say it is very broad. The players then receive payoffs according to the outcome of that function and since I'm assuming that's what the players care about (monetary payoffs) - the utilities are known.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the Implementation Problem.  Since you are asking for dominant strategies, the Gibbard-Satterthwaite theorem applies.  With at least three people, and using unrestricted utilities, and there exist preferences so that your choice rule will pick out any given actual outcome, then the choice function is dictatorial.  That is, there is someone who gets his favorite outcome no matter what others think.  If preferences can be restricted, something called the Groves-Ledyard mechanism can work, and if you allow weaker forms of agreement, such as Nash or Subgame perfect equilibrium, there are more choices. See chapter 10 of Osborne and Rubinstein's A Course in Game Theory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm aware of these concepts, but they don't quite answer my question. In my case, I'm not only restricting the preferences, but I'm creating an exact utility function that I know all parties work by. The reason is simple - there are no hidden agendas. Parties are profit-maximizing and the utilities are direct payments.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps, in my situation, it is better to 'fix the game' with the specific payoffs, instead of using implementation theory? I haven't seen this done in a lot in papers, but in my case the payoffs and the rules are known.

Comment: Well, if you know the rules, that puts you more in traditional game theory, where you are looking for equilibrium strategies given preferences and the rules.  Implementation theory is more given preferences, how do you design a game form to get the outcome you want.  It sounds like  you might be looking at an auction, for which there are lots of results.